# Distribute identical objects to different people with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways can we distribute 26 identical objects to 5 distinct people if the first person can only have 8 or 9 objects and the second person cannot have more than 10 objects?

Solution -: coefficient of $x^{26}$ in $(x^8+x^9)(x^0+....+x^{10})(x^0+....+x^{26})^3$ which is 2266 ways
Is this correct?

Comment: At least the generating function looks correct to me.

Comment: @MattiP. Could you confirm the final result as well?

Comment: $2266$ is correct.

Comment: Correct, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialQuotient%5B%28x%5E8%2Bx%5E9%29%28x%5E11-1%29%28x%5E27-1%29%5E3%2C%28x-1%29%5E4%2Cx%5D).